# How to test a device that has a static ip by directly connecting it to my dev PC?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, server

I have a server removed from the server farm, to do some testing on it in-office. I want to connect to the Integrated Lights-out manager, but it is set to a static public ip (starts with 195....).

Is there any way that I can connect this server to my Ubuntu dev machine by directly connecting it to my ethernet interface with a lan cable, and then access it through its static ip?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a specially-wired crossover cable, for a direct connection, or plug both into a hub/switch. On your dev machine, you would probably need to set a static IP as well, with an IP address and subnet mask that allowed both machines to see one another.